# What happens if i overwrite the return address on the stack?

Tags: c++, c, stack-overflow

I know this is dangerous behaviour, but I would like to figure out what happened.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

static int count = 0;

void hello(void){
    count ++;  
    fprintf(stderr,"hello! %d\n",count);
}

void foo(void){
    void *buf[10];
    static int i;

    for(i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++){ // put enough data to overwrite the return address on the stack
        buf[i] = hello;
    }
}

int main(void){
    int buf[1000];
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the result:

```
……
hello! 83
hello! 84
hello! 85
hello! 86
hello! 87
hello! 88
hello! 89
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why has the hello function been called 89 times?
When the function `foo` returns, the pc register should get the address of hello function, shouldn't it?
So hello is called and the code inside is executed, then what? Shouldn't the program return to main function? Where does the "89" came from? I seem to be missing something, could someone please point it out to me .

Comment: Which compiler /operating system are you using? Also, you do know that buf in main and buf in foo have nothing to do with each other, right?

Comment: @Ashalynd centos 7, gcc

Comment: Which version of gcc?

Comment: @Ashalynd gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)

Comment: By the way, your program does not get back to main, because it crashes during the cycle in foo.

Comment: @Ashalynd I see. But why keep calling hello? I just change the data memory area , not code memory area, isn't pc get the next address from code memory area?

Comment: You said yourself that you overwrote the return address, so `main` can't be returned to. Your program "returns" to `hello` until it crashes.

Comment: @molbdnilo So, when foo finish , the program got hello address, then hello finish, it got hello address again?

Comment: See the description in @antron's answer, which is spot on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You wrote the address of the function `hello` to the stack of `foo` 90 times beyond  the amount of space you reserved with `buf`. When `foo` tried to return, it loaded (one of) the first extra address(es) of `hello` into the program counter, popped it, and "returned" to it. The reason I say "one of" is because there may be some space on the stack between the end of the array you reserved and the beginning of the return address.

`hello` assumed that it was called by `foo`. However, it was not called, in other words, the address of the remainder of `foo` was not pushed onto the stack for `hello` to return to. So, when `hello` returned, the thing it popped was the next thing on the stack, which was again the address of `hello`.

This again looked like a call from `hello`'s point of view, but it was not actually a call, since it was a return, so `hello` kept returning to itself and popping one address of `hello` from the stack each time, until it ran out of such addresses.

After those ran out, the next bytes on the stack, which you had not overwritten, when treated as a pointer, were to elsewhere in memory, probably to something that was not allocated to your process memory map. `hello` tried to return to that, and that's when the program segfaulted.

Comment: That's what i want to know, Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Well this is **undefined** behavior. When you  step into unallocated memory **anything** can happen depending on what "junk" there is at the moment.

Segmentation fault basically means that you stepped out of the protected memory of your program (in your case it took "89 times"). Your operating system defends you against this and tells you that you tried to write outside of the space allocated for the program.

(This was not the case in old operating systems and such a bug could cause your operating system to crash if your program overflowed into system space.)

Answer (score 1):

As Nahum says, it is undefined behaviour, but this does not mean it can't be explained:

```
100 - 89 = 11
```

An this is, precisely, the size of your local stack (void *[10] + int).

Try this (undefined behaviour, could erase your hard disk or fix the global economy):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

static int count = 0;

static void hello(void){
    count ++;  
    fprintf(stderr,"hello! %d\n",count);
}

static void foo(void){
    void *buf[1];
    static int i;

    for(i = 0 ; i <= 100 + 2; i++){ // put enough data to overwrite the return address on stack
        buf[i] = hello;
    }
}

static void bye(void) {
    printf("Bye, bye...\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(void){
    void *buf[1000];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        buf[i] = &bye;
    }
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```